# How to display image preview without downloading from given url using PHP?

Tags: php, image, curl

So I'm working on a project to fetch images from fashion websites. Now I'm implementing the add item function in the website. In this function, user needs to input website url first, then the web **scraper** will **scrape** the target images' url and pass the urls to the curl to download the image. Finally the add item popup window will preview the images I fetched in the previous step and ask the user to fill out some basic information for the items. Everything works fine except that the curl will take a very long time to download the images (cuz the images from those fashion website are often very high-quality). So I'm wondering is there a way I can create a preview without actually downloading the full-size images and do the download when the user fill out basic information later. Thanks!

Comment: I guess your best bet would be to *hotlink* those images (if possible). So it's not your system that downloads them for preview, but the users client.

Answer (score 0):

If the fashion website has smaller versions of the images, you should download those first. You can use them for your preview.

If the fashion website only has the full size image, there is no way to download a smaller version of it.

You probably know what your doing, but remember that you should respect the copyright of images on websites, especially art websites such as fashion websites. Be careful with what you do with them.

Comment: ..we are legally cooperating with the website we download image from

Comment: So is there by any chance I can preview the image without downloading them first, or is there any way I can reduce the delay?

Comment: In order to have a preview, the fashion website should offer this functionality, if it doesn't, you're out of luck I'm afraid.

Comment: You can try to make the website more responsive, by downloading the images one by one and updating the page as the new images start coming in. This is a bit tricky though, unless you are good at javascript.